# How should I troubleshoot a very slow MySQL server droplet?

Tags: mysql-8.0, ubuntu

I'm new to the DBA forum, but not SO, and I've searched for answers on this, and tried what I've found.

We have a Rails app that lives on a Digital Ocean droplet, and a bigger and more powerful droplet for the db. Both are shared CPU droplets.

I'm trying to diagnose very slow query times on MySQL, that got 2x slower today when i ran `apt upgrade` on the Ubuntu 20 OS.

We are working on optimizing our Rails queries separately and I realize this is usually most of the problem. The reason I feel it may be a server issue is (1) the upgrade today slowed things down (2) Expensive queries **locally** are slow but reasonable: say, 1s on a 9 year old computer. On the **server**, the exact same query takes ~10x as long.

Another indication is, when we made an attempt last year to `dist-upgrade` the db server to Ubuntu 22, we had to roll it back because it blew up our query times in a similar way.

I can post my config file, our slow query log, and whatever else would help, but I don't want to waste anyone's time if i'm asking the wrong questions or missing something obvious.

**Additional info:**

- OS: Ubuntu 20.10 (GNU/Linux 5.8.0-48-generic x86_64)
- CPU: shared, 8 virtual cores (DO)
- RAM: 16GB
- Storage: 320GB NVMe disk, of which 3.8% used

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 4 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - Thank you! I added the server info in the question, and I've uploaded the mysql server output text here: https://jpst.it/3zcH5. It's a ton of stuff, but the formatting isn't as illegible as I thought.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  Workload Analysis in process.

Comment: Do you have Replication Instance running at DO?  Since you are on a Digital Ocean shared server, please ask DO to provide from OS Command Prompt, TEXT results of ulimit -a report so we can see the OS limits available.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - thank you, appreciate it! I have requested those results. We don't have a replication instance.

Comment: I'm not sure DO support is going to provide me with text ouptut from running `ulimit -a report`. Their support has been very disengaged, they don't seem to understand the request. We don't have a support plan, either. I'm still trying though.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section,

```
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=3  #  from 8 you only have 8 cores, leave some for other processes.
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function.
read_rnd_buffer_size=16384  # from 256K to reduce Handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 127,615.
innodb_io_capacity=900  # from 200 to use more of available NVME IOPS.
table_open_cache_instances=2  # from 16 to stay below total cores requested.
```

These suggestions should improve response time, when implemented and stop/start instance.

There are many more opportunities to improve your configuration to improve speed of processing. Pleaes view profile.

Comment: Thank you Wilson - trying those suggestions this morning, will report back. I was able to get the report from `ulimit` after all: https://jpst.it/3zwlR

Comment: @nimmolo  Any feedback on suggestions?  Better/worse?

Comment: Definitely better, server load is way down. I will send more details when I can dig into them, i want to check the slow query log too. THANK YOU.

Comment: If you will post last 40 lines of your Slow Query Log, I will try to give you a hand up.  Additional info will probably be required after initial review of your log.